# Convert table column data type from blob to raw

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, oracle12c

I have a table designed like,

```
create table tbl ( 
  id number(5),
  data blob
);
```

Its found that the column `data` have 
very small size data, which can be stored in `raw(200)`:

so the new table would be,

```
create table tbl ( 
  id number(5),
  data raw(200)
);
```

How can I migrate this table to new design ***without loosing the data in it***.

Comment: Look at `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit lengthy method, but it works if you are sure that your `data` column values don't go beyond 200 in length.

> 1. Create a table to hold the contents of `tbl` temporarily

```
create table tbl_temp as select * from tbl;
Rem -- Ensure that tbl_temp contains all the contents
select * from tbl_temp;
Rem -- Double verify by subtracting the contents
select * from tbl minus select * from tbl_temp;
```

> 2. Delete the contents in `tbl`

```
delete from tbl;
commit;
```

> 3. Drop column `data`

```
alter table tbl drop column data;
```

> 4. Create a column `data` with `raw(200)` type

```
alter table tbl add data raw(200);
```

> 5. Select & insert from the temporary table created

```
insert into tbl select id, dbms_lob.substr(data,200,1) from tbl_temp;
commit;
```

We are using `substr` method of `dbms_lob` package which returns `raw` type data. So, the resulted value can be directly inserted.